# How can i line up a group of buttons next to a bootstrap 3 panel title using CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to learn some bootstrap 3, and i'm trying to add a group of two buttons to a panel heading for those [Collapse-Accordion's](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).
I want to be able to line the title of the panel to the left, and the `btn-group` lined to the right.

I have tried to add `pull-left` for the title, and `pull-right` for the button group, but this will not result in something pretty...

Adding for example: `style="margin-left:200px;"` to the `<span>`, will work, but when i add more panels, with different names, there will be another number of px for that margin...

Here is a link to my [JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/q8br8/6/)

Where i go wrong is probably somewhere here: Not sure if i can use the `<span>` within the `<h4>`, and for this purpose of mine?

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
           Click me...
     </a>
     <span class="btn-group"> 
        <button class="btn btn-default">ON</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary active">OFF</button>
    </span>
  </h4>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

pls try the below code, and here is the [fiddle](http://bootply.com/92133)

```
        <div class="panel-heading">

                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                       <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"        href="#collapseOne">Click me...
                        </a>
                           </div>
                       <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                       <span class="btn-group"> 
                            <button class="btn btn-default">ON</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary active">OFF</button>
                        </span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </h4>  

                </div>
```

Comment: It does not work for small devices, which is the issue i am having, (but perhaps not stated). I want it to line up correctly when seen on a phone, which is most important. Any ideas?

Comment: it should work for all devices if you are using the grid class as "col-xs-.."

Comment: see the updated fiddle, http://bootply.com/92146# and click on the mobile icon and see the page and adjust the browser

Comment: it seems to be working, however, the "Click me..." (the title) is not aligned in the middle of the header box. The position of it to the left is accurate, but its not centered height-wise. =/

Answer (score 0):

if you change some of the css rules for the panel-head and btn-group it work.

```
.btn-group{
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 8px;
}

.panel-heading{
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q8qCW/1/

I would suggest, not to add these rules to every panel-head and btn-group ^^. I also change the size of the btn-group to.

```
btn-group-xs
```

It is not a very dynamic way if doing it, but gets the job done.
Other sizes of btn-groups are possible, but require different top and right css rules.

Comment: If this would have worked without the `btn-group-xs`, it would have been golden.

Comment: just use different top and right settings ^^ 2px for both should do, but then there is a very narrow gap, I used btn-group-xs just for looks ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Click me...
</a>
<span class="btn-group col-md-offset-9">
    <button class="btn btn-default">ON</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary active">OFF</button>
</span>
```

Hi i have forked your code to js fiddle and added some class and media queries(for idea), please try to improve media queries as well.

you can find it [here](HTTP://jsfiddle.net/santosh_patnala/TNmCj/8/)

Comment: it's for the small devices i want it to line up correctly. =/

Comment: for smaller devices please write the media queries accordingly which i have given in fiddle as an example... please review and write queries accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `list-inline`..

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="col-xs-12">
          <span class="btn-group pull-right"> 
             <button class="btn btn-default">ON</button>
             <button class="btn btn-primary active">OFF</button>
            </span>
           <h4>
             <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
               Click me...
             </a>
          </h4>
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/92157